# Operation with two string textboxes separated by a comma vb net

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 strings of numbers: like this:

```
Textbox1.Text = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11
Textbox2.Text = 11,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

I want to calculate, display in textbox3, their sum, + or - or * or /

all value from textbox1.text + all values from textbox2.text

Textbox3.Text = `12,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12`

I would like, though, and a specification where I can change the sign, instead of + being -, or / or * depending on my choice.

this code is a bit cumbersome, I would like to improve it with something simpler.

```
    Dim str1 As String
    'Set your string value
    str1 = TxtBoxLstDrawsPlus.Text
    Dim str2 As String
    'Set your string value
    str2 = TxtBoxLstDrawsMinus.Text
    Dim strWords As String() = str1.Split(",")
    Dim strWordsAAA As String() = str2.Split(",")
    TextBox6.Text &= Val(strWords(0)) + Val(strWordsAAA(0)) & "," & Val(strWords(1)) + Val(strWordsAAA(1)) & "," & Val(strWords(2)) + Val(strWordsAAA(2)) & "," & Val(strWords(3)) + Val(strWordsAAA(3)) & "," & Val(strWords(4)) + Val(strWordsAAA(4)) & "," & Val(strWords(5)) + Val(strWordsAAA(5)) & "," & Val(strWords(6)) + Val(strWordsAAA(6)) & "," & Val(strWords(7)) + Val(strWordsAAA(7)) & "," & Val(strWords(8)) + Val(strWordsAAA(8)) & "," & Val(strWords(9)) + Val(strWordsAAA(9)) & "," & Val(strWords(10)) + Val(strWordsAAA(10)) & "," & Val(strWords(11)) + Val(strWordsAAA(11)) & "," & Val(strWords(12)) + Val(strWordsAAA(12)) & "," & Val(strWords(13)) + Val(strWordsAAA(13)) & "," & Val(strWords(14)) + Val(strWordsAAA(14)) & "," & Val(strWords(15)) + Val(strWordsAAA(15)) & "," & Val(strWords(16)) + Val(strWordsAAA(16)) & "," & Val(strWords(17)) + Val(strWordsAAA(17)) & "," & Val(strWords(18)) + Val(strWordsAAA(18)) & "," & Val(strWords(19)) + Val(strWordsAAA(19))
```

Comment: You should be looping through those values instead of assuming index 19 is there.

Comment: Make an array holding all the numbers you want to work with `Dim strNumbers As String() = (Textbox1.Text & "," & Textbox2.Text).Split(",")`, Create a box to hold your running total `Dim runningTotal As Integer = 0`. Then `For Each strNum As String In strNumbers` : `runningTotal += CInt(strNum) 'or -=, *=, etc`. Finally just show what your running total result is `TextBox6.Text = runningTotal.ToString`

Comment: the count is reset after each loop. I should make him stop resetting.

Comment: The obvious answer is to use a `For` loop. You need to combine values based on their index and a `For` loop is the one that provides an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the input strings (`TextBox1.Text` and `TextBox2.Text`), [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) the string arrays to produce a result array, and finally `String.Join` it in `TextBox3`:

Here's in one line:

```vb
TextBox3.Text = String.Join(",", TextBox1.Text.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    Zip(TextBox2.Text.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
        Function(x, y) CInt(x) + CInt(y)))
```

You can use the same approach to do different arithmetic operations:

```vb
Dim opr As Char = "+"c '<- From your arithmetic operation selector like ComboBox.

TextBox3.Text = String.Join(",", TextBox1.Text.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    Select(Function(x) CInt(x)).
    Zip(TextBox2.Text.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    Select(Function(y) CInt(y)),
        Function(x, y)
            Select Case opr
                Case "-"c
                    Return x - y
                Case "*"c
                    Return x * y
                Case "/"c
                    Return x \ y
                Case Else
                    Return x + y
            End Select
        End Function))
```

It'll be a good idea if you'd validate your inputs first:

```vb
Dim Arr1() = TextBox1.Text.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim Arr2() = TextBox2.Text.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim opr As Char = OprTextBox.Text.ElementAtOrDefault(0) 'A TextBox this time as another example.
Dim ValidOpr() As Char = {"+"c, "-"c, "*"c, "/"c}

If Arr1.Length <> Arr2.Length OrElse
    Arr1.Any(Function(x) Not Integer.TryParse(x, Nothing)) OrElse
    Arr2.Any(Function(x) Not Integer.TryParse(x, Nothing)) OrElse
    Not ValidOpr.Contains(Opr) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Excuse me ... !?!?")
    Return
End If

'You have valid inputs. Proceed...

TextBox3.Text = String.Join(",", Arr1.Select(Function(x) CInt(x)).
    Zip(Arr2.Select(Function(x) CInt(x)),
        Function(x, y)
            Select Case opr
                Case "-"c
                    Return x - y
                Case "*"c
                    Return x * y
                Case "/"c
                    Return x \ y
                Case Else
                    Return x + y
            End Select
        End Function))
```

Better yet, `enum` the arithmetic operations:

```vb
Public Enum ArithmeticOperations
    Add
    Subtract
    Multiply
    Divide
End Enum
```

.. and create a parameterized `Function` that returns the joined string.

```vb
'You name it...
Public Function GetCalcString(input1 As String,
                                input2 As String,
                                opr As ArithmeticOperations) As String

    Dim Arr1() = input1.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim Arr2() = input2.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    If Arr1.Length <> Arr2.Length OrElse
        Arr1.Any(Function(x) Not Integer.TryParse(x, Nothing)) OrElse
        Arr2.Any(Function(x) Not Integer.TryParse(x, Nothing)) Then
        Return Nothing         
    End If

    Return String.Join(",", Arr1.Select(Function(x) CInt(x)).
                        Zip(Arr2.Select(Function(x) CInt(x)),
                            Function(x, y)
                                Select Case opr
                                    Case ArithmeticOperation.Subtract
                                        Return x - y
                                    Case ArithmeticOperation.Multiply
                                        Return x * y
                                    Case ArithmeticOperation.Divide
                                        Return x \ y
                                    Case Else
                                        Return x + y
                                End Select
                            End Function))
End Function
```

Assuming that, the arithmetic operations are listed in a `ComboBox` in the same order:

```vb
Private Sub TheCaller()
    TextBox3.Text = GetCalcString(TextBox1.Text,
                                  TextBox12.Text,
                                  CType(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex, ArithmeticOperations))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can clearly learn the analysis of what is presented above. especially as it is, it is a detailed presentation, and helpful. it will be very useful to be able i'm to play with what is presented.